# Citizenship or citizenships?

Tags: grammar

Which is the best option?

In Europe, national and supranational citizenship may coexist.

In Europe, national and supranational citizenships may coexist.

Comment: Careful how you go (sailing term): https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780198805854.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780198805854-e-29

Comment: @Lambie Your comment confuses me (and is very likely to be even more so to a learner and first time contributor like Luiz Marcelo).  What guidance does the linked webpage offer? I can’t even see citizenship used in the plural although it is discussing multiple citizenships.

Comment: I am trying to suggest that supranational citizenship is a concept and to have a citizenship in a country is another. I doubt you can put both in the same sentence. The guidance is conceptual. Both together like that don't make sense to me.

Comment: Indeed, what I want to state is that the concept of citizenship is no longer restricted to national boundaries, therefore in Europe, for instance, a new phenomenon is arising: regional citizenship. People are German or French, but also (and at the same time) European. So, what I want to summarise in one sentence is that both these phenomena (national or traditional citizenship and regional citizenship) can coexist. It is easy to state such idea in any Latine language, since "citizenship" is a countable noun, but it is really hard to express this idea in English - at least for me, a foreigner

Comment: It's easy in English, two. I have two citizenships, in fact. But generally, we'd say a dual citizenship. See here for citizenships: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_citizenship Also, you can use multiple citizenship for more than two.

Comment: Ok. Yes “dual citizenship” is definitely the idiomatic way to say it in Australia, as we have had constitutional issues around members of Parliament with undeclared dual citizenship. 
But as far as the question goes (and leaving aside analysis of the content) I’d say that Luiz Marcelo’s best option was to use the plural “citizenships”.

Comment: Thank you very much!!